# Hybrid mobile app - Is it possible to change old android webview ui?

Tags: android, cordova, webview, ionic-framework, hybrid

I am learning ionic framework for hybrid app development. I am currently on 5.1.1 but the apps developed with ionic seems to be using older android ui elements such as text selectors, alert dialogs. Also if I don't style form elements they also look very outdate.

A simple example:

Newer text selector:

[image]

Older text selector:

[image]

Is it possible to change these elements? I tried installing crosswalk browser but it did not affect these at all.

Comment: That depends on the value of `targetSdkVersion` of your app. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target

Comment: targetSdkVersion is 22 and I set the minimum one to 21 but nothing changed. I was expecting some material design ui elements.

Comment: I have the "Older text selector" in my ASUS zenfone3. It's annoying for it slow down the select-text operation.
Some people reported in below link that it happens in " iPhones, Xperia's, Asus Zenfone and some early HTC phones", but no one reported a way to disable it. 
https://forum.xda-developers.com/x-compact/help/how-to-off-long-press-magnification-t3750924